# Clone LVM based installation to larger drive and extend root partition to use new space

Tags: partitioning, lvm, clone

There are a few similar questions online but I haven't seen any that cover the exact scenario. This is a question and answer in one to a problem that took me several hours to work out.

I wanted to clone a drive and maintain /boot without having to mess around with grub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot up on a live CD/USB and then use dd to clone from the old disk to the new one:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

Shutdown and remove old drive to avoid vg conflicts
Actually what I did is clone /dev/sda to a file on third drive so I could a) have a backup and b) start from scratch fairly easily.
If you run the dd step again, reboot as pvdisplay will still show the old statistics.

```
shutdown -h now
```

After booting up on live cd/usb again, sdb becomes sda

use parted to create a new partition after all existing partitions. I found parted to be easier than fdisk in this case because you can just tell it to use all available space

```
gparted /dev/sda
```

Now create a new physical volume. Some people suggest changing the existing pv size (pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize), but this never worked for me and resulted in errors at the lvextend step

```
pvcreate /dev/sda3 (The new partition)
vgextend /dev/vgname /dev/sda3
```

You should now see the additional free space

```
vgdisplay
```

Apologies for the lack of output, I'm not running all of this again :D

Now we need to extend the lvm partition. Note that if you have a swap partition at the end, don't worry, lvm handles that for you.

```
lvextend /dev/vgname/root -L+150G
```

(vgdisplay showed you how much space you could add)

```
lvscan
```

This will show you that the space has been allocated, but we're still not quite there, df won't show the additional free space.

```
e2fsck -f /dev/vgname/root
resize2fs /dev/vgname/root
```

Now we should be there, if you mount up /dev/vgname/root, df will report the new partition size and free space.

Remove your live CD/USB and reboot, your install should work.

These steps worked with a Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 install and a Ubuntu 16.04.2 live USB.